# in pyecharts, how to bring line to front of bar when using bar.overlap(line)?

Tags: python, django, echarts

unfortunatly there is no tag for pyecharts in stackoverflow site , I'm not sure if I will get a helpful answer , hopefully I will get

I have the following chart that consists of two bars and one line, I need 2 things :

1. I need to bring the line to front of bar , its under the bar by default
2. I need to shorten the value number to the nearest thousand (e.g 80,000 = 80K)

code :-

```
from pyecharts.charts import Bar, Gauge, Line
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.globals import ThemeType

bar = (
    Bar(init_opts=opts.InitOpts(width='100%', theme=ThemeType.VINTAGE))

    .add_xaxis(["Category-1" , "Category-2", "Category-3", "Category-4", "Category-5"])
    .add_yaxis('No. Of Investments', [100,700,900,500,400,50], label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(is_show=False),)
    .add_yaxis('No. Of Investors', [24,65,30,41,88], label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(is_show=False),)
    .extend_axis(
        yaxis=opts.AxisOpts(
            name="Value",
            type_="value", 
            name_textstyle_opts=opts.TextStyleOpts(font_size=14, font_weight='bold', font_family='Dubai')
        )
    )
    .set_global_opts(legend_opts=opts.LegendOpts(is_show=True , 
                                                    pos_right = 0,
                                                    textstyle_opts = opts.TextStyleOpts(font_size=14, font_weight='bold', font_family='Dubai') ),
                        yaxis_opts=opts.AxisOpts(
                                                name='Count',
                                                name_location='middle',
                                                name_gap=50,
                                                type_="value",
                                                axistick_opts=opts.AxisTickOpts(is_show=True),
                                                splitline_opts=opts.SplitLineOpts(is_show=True),
                                                axispointer_opts=opts.AxisPointerOpts(is_show=False),
                                                name_textstyle_opts=opts.TextStyleOpts(
                                                    font_size=14, font_weight='bold', font_family='Dubai')
                                            ),
                    xaxis_opts=opts.AxisOpts(   type_="category",
                                                axispointer_opts=opts.AxisPointerOpts(is_show=True, type_="shadow"),
                                                name_textstyle_opts=opts.TextStyleOpts(font_size=14, font_weight='bold', font_family='Dubai') , 
                                                axislabel_opts = opts.LabelOpts(font_family='Dubai' , 
                                                                                rotate = 30,
                                                                                font_size= 11, 
                                                                                )
                                            ),
                    tooltip_opts=opts.TooltipOpts(
                                                    is_show=True,
                                                    trigger="axis",
                                                    textstyle_opts = opts.TextStyleOpts( font_family='Dubai')
                                                ) , 
                    toolbox_opts  = opts.ToolboxOpts(is_show=True , pos_left= '5%', 
                                                        feature=opts.ToolBoxFeatureOpts(
                                                            data_zoom = opts.ToolBoxFeatureDataZoomOpts(is_show=False) , 
                                                            data_view =  opts.ToolBoxFeatureDataViewOpts(is_show=False) ,
                                                            brush=None
                                                        ) )

    )
)

line = (
Line()
.add_xaxis(["Category-1" , "Category-2", "Category-3", "Category-4", "Category-5"])
.add_yaxis('Investments Valaue', [50500,60020,84000,30150,41200],
            yaxis_index=1, 
            label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(is_show=False),
            linestyle_opts = opts.LineStyleOpts(width=2)
        )

)
bar.overlap(line).render_notebook()
```

[image]

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to avoid overlap between a bar chart and a line chart in pyecharts seems to be missing from the documentation and [examples](https://gallery.pyecharts.org/#/Bar/multiple_y_axes) provided. When trying to combine a bar chart and a line chart, the bar chart always appears in front of the line chart, regardless of the order in which the charts are added to the plot. As a workaround, you can add transparency to the bar chart to make the line chart partially visible over the bar chart.

```
itemstyle_opts=opts.ItemStyleOpts(opacity=0.8)
```